# Suppose that $A \in M_{5\times5}$, and suppose that $RREF_A = B$. Find $\text{rank}(A)$, if we know that $\det A = \det B + 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

Suppose that $A \in M_{5\times5}$, and suppose that $RREF_A = B$. Find $\text{rank}(A)$, if we know that $\det A = \det B + 1$

I'm not really sure how to approach this question. I know that $n = 5$ ($A$ has $5$ columns), so $\text{rank}(A) + \text{nullity}(A) = 5$. I also know that $\det(A) \neq \det(B) \neq 0$ because that would just be nonsense. However I don't know what other steps to take to find an answer. I believe it is the case that if $\det(A) \neq 0$, then $\text{rank}(A) = n = 5$, but I'm not really sure if that's true or (if it is true) how to justify that it is the case.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\det A = 0$, then $\det B = 0$ as well because $B$ is obtained from $A$ through either swapping rows or multiplying a row by a non-zero number** (hence $\det B = \alpha \det A$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$). You can also argue that if $\det A = 0$, then $A$ has two linearly dependent rows, hence $B$ must have at least a zero row, and so has determinant zero as well.

Therefore $\det A \neq 0$ and rank$(A) = 5$.

** There is another possible row operation, but it doesn't affect the determinant.